# Importing ERD (.mwb file) from MySQL Workbench to Lucidchart or Drawio

Tags: mysql-workbench, erd, lucidchart

I have created the ERD on MySQL Workbench and exported it as .mwb file. I want to import this ERD into Lucidchart or any other diagram platform. I would to make chanages on the ERD.

Is there a nay way to trasfer the ERD from MySQL Workbench to Lucidchart?

Please help me, ERD is huge. Therefore, I need to transfer.

I have tried to change file extention but it did not work. I am not sure whether i change it right way.

Comment: You either need to find a converter program (such question is off topic here) or you need to write a converter program yourself.